# TTS- convert to WAV file

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i have successfully written and executed code for text to speech.
the code is able to speak out the text written in edittext.
but now i dont know how to convert it into .wav file and save it into directory.
as i am writing this code for api 15+, plz suggest me something.

my code:

```
@Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
              //  btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }
    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
```

please some one help me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I save my android tts output in a wav file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713594/how-can-i-save-my-android-tts-output-in-a-wav-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`synthetizeToFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String)).
You have to create a `File` with `FileProvider` to avoid restricted files above api 24. You have also to pass a request id.

```
String utteranceId = "MyUtteranceId"
File file = /* file obtained with FileProvider */
int result = tts.synthesizeToFile(text, null, file, utteranceId);
if (result == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
    // It was successfull.
} else {
    // Error occurred
}
```

This method returns an int representing the result (error or success).
I recommend you to move the synthetize on a background thread and dispatch the result on the UI thread after.

Take a look also to the *File rendering and playback* section of:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html